# Flutter showing widget by for loop showing error

Tags: flutter

I need to call widget multiple time. Mean i am fetching data and showing in a widget by for loop. Issue is when i am showing that widget its showing error

My code

```
class _CartPageState extends State<CartPage> {

  void navigateToAddressPage() {
    Get.to(AddressPage());
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    this._query();
  }
  List<Widget> textWidgetList = List<Widget>();

  void _query() async {
    print('cart');
    final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;

    final allRows = await dbHelper.queryAllRows();
    print(allRows);
    print('query all rows:');
    allRows.forEach((row) => print(row));

    for (int i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {

      textWidgetList.add(
          Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 120.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl:
                      'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/7f/0f/dc/7f0fdc10a9cb26e78d8e6257e1b06fb6.jpg',
                      height: 100.0,
                      width: 100.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Nike Air Zoom Pegasus 36 Miami',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                  maxLines: 3,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    child: Icon(
                                      FlutterIcons.delete_outline_mco,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  '\$50',
                                ),
                              ),
                              // Counter(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )


    );
    }

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(context),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Divider(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(.5)),
              SizedBox(height: 12.0),
              Column(children: textWidgetList()),//here is error 
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              buildCoupunBox(context),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              buildPriceBox(context),
              SizedBox(height: 18.0),
              buildCheckoutButton(),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Its showing this error `The expression doesn't evaluate to a function`, so it can't be invoked. How can i solve this error ? I am simply using for loop and show a widget in a column but dont know why its showing this error. I have comment where is the error showing .

Answer (score 1):

This error simply says that you should remove the "()", because `textWidgetList` is not a function but a variable.